# How can I smoothly scale a specific region in a signal with Python / Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I need to scale a curve as shown on the picture underneath. The curve is a two-dimensional array consisting of many X and Y values. It is important that the curve stays continuous and there is no "leap" at the place where I want to cut. Do you have any ideas? Is there a function/functions in python that can do this?

[image: blue curve needed, red was the initial]

Comment: I'm not clear on what type of scaling you need.  The changes are not a simple linear factor.  It *appears* that the range in question both starts and ends at an x-intercept; this would give you continuity for a multiplicative change (i.e. multiply by a factor).  There is likely no such Python function, but a NumPy lambda function might well yield what you want.  Please clarify with an example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes, I just have scaled the function based on the intersection with the time axis. But what if I want to scale a peak (part of a function) that is not going through X=0 (I am going to upload a new, better picture)? 
Just imagine that the curve is shifted so it is not going through X=0. Should I shift it back to X=0, scale the part that I need (with lambda) and shift it back again to where it was?
I thought, there is probably a NumPy function that can do this steps for me.
And what about the "leaps" at the positons where the scaled and the unscaled parts unite?  I have to somehow smoot them.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom filter with smooth transitions at the edges and use that for scaling. One approach would be to apply a convolution with a Gaussian normal distribution to a box function and use the result as window. ([scipy.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html))

[image: from scipy.convolve]

(image from scipy.convolve)

Here some code to get you started.
Of course you can control the steepness of the filter edges by adjusting the parameter of `signal.hann(50)`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
sig = np.repeat([0., 1., 0.], 100)
print(sig)
win = signal.hann(50)
filtered = signal.convolve(sig, win, mode='same') / sum(win)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax_orig, ax_win, ax_filt, ax_scal) = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True)
ax_orig.plot(sig)
ax_orig.set_title('Original pulse')
ax_orig.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_win.plot(win)
ax_win.set_title('Filter impulse response')
ax_win.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_filt.plot(filtered)
ax_filt.set_title('Filtered signal')
ax_filt.margins(0, 0.1)


x = np.linspace(0.0, 300, 300)
y = np.sin(x)

ax_scal.plot(x, y)

ax_scal.plot(x, y * (filtered + 1), 'r-')

ax_scal.set_title('Scaled signal')
ax_scal.margins(0, 0.1)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]